Emoji реакции от бота, Aiogram
Как сделать так, что бы при отправке сообщения "да" бот ставил реакцию "" на сообщение? Aiogram 3.4

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/methods/set_message_reaction.html

Для отправки реакции используйте message.react:
@router.message(F.text == 'да')
async def reaction(message: Message):
    emoji = ReactionTypeEmoji(emoji='')
    await message.react([emoji])

и не забудьте сделать импорт from aiogram.types import ReactionTypeEmoji

Попробуйте так:
@dp.message_handler()
async def check_message(message: Message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'да':
        await message.reply("")


в вашем примере бот будет цитировать сообщение, а автор вопроса интересовался о том, как ставить реакцию, так что ваш ответ не подходит

Почему так думаете?

А почему ты думаешь не так?

@Andrey наверное потому что автор именно так и написал при отправке сообщения "да" бот ставил реакцию ""

Да, верно, правильнее message.answer
